# Create User In Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I know that there is a build in module Orchard.Users. 
I want to include the user registration, Login, Forget password (etc) into My Custom Module.

I read the Orchard Documentation but I didn't find any thing useful related to this topic. Search Google leads me to answers like ADMIN -> SETTINGS - > USERS -> Add User but this is what I don't need.

I need to include the Login, User Registration in My Own Module. Please refer me to some article or suggest.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first you should turn on user registration (ADMIN->SETTINGS->USERS->Users can create new accounts on the site)
Then you'll have access to `~/Users/Account/Register`

Also read these discussions:

- http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/258455
- http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/258197
- http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/281070