# How to enable user registration in Orchard CMS 1.7 (RC)

Tags: orchardcms

I want to allow people who visit my Orchard CMS **1.7** (RC) site to be able to sign up as users.

In 1.6 it was very easy (See: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077835/orchard-cms-simple-user-registration-authentication) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324495/create-user-in-orchard-cms))

However I can't seem to find that option anywhere in **1.7**

Is it:

- Hiding?
- Missing?
- Needs to be enabled via a new module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can still see the option.

It's at: `/Admin/Settings/Users`

Then check: `Users can create new accounts on the site`

Comment: Really?! I must be blind. <goes back to check>

Comment: Ok, so it is. It wasn't there when I had it running locally but now I have deployed it; it is there. Odd. <Shrug> thanks all the same.